# Why doesn't entity framework wizard see my foreign keys in chinook database?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a simple Entity model for the chinook database with all the tables and Vs2010 isn't creating any relationships or navigation properties. They certainly exist, they appear in a database diagram in SSMS.

I have another machine (also vs2010 sp1 and sql express 2008 r2) that isn't having this problem, but I have no idea what's different there.

Here's what the created model looks like:
[image: Chinook Model Without Associations]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skip the following lines when creating your database. I believe they confuse EF:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IPK_Album] ON [dbo].[Album]([AlbumId]);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IPK_Artist] ON [dbo].[Artist]([ArtistId]);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IPK_Customer] ON [dbo].[Customer]([CustomerId]);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IPK_Employee] ON [dbo].[Employee]([EmployeeId]);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IPK_Genre] ON [dbo].[Genre]([GenreId]);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IPK_Invoice] ON [dbo].[Invoice]([InvoiceId]);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IPK_InvoiceLine] ON [dbo].[InvoiceLine]([InvoiceLineId]);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IPK_MediaType] ON [dbo].[MediaType]([MediaTypeId]);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IPK_Playlist] ON [dbo].[Playlist]([PlaylistId]);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IPK_PlaylistTrack] ON [dbo].[PlaylistTrack]([PlaylistId], [TrackId]);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IPK_Track] ON [dbo].[Track]([TrackId]);
GO
```

Comment: Thanks! A microsoft moderator said the same thing: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/0817b285-5e76-4c8c-909a-cda675f7096f

Comment: That's not a good sign, having to remove the indexes, but it worked for me with EF 4.1

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are targeting the .NET Framework 4.0 in your project's compile options.

Also, make sure that you have checked the option to include relationships in your model.

[image]

[More Details Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046956/missing-something-with-entity-framework-for-net-3-5)

[And some Background Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/11/06/foreign-key-relationships-in-the-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: My console app was set to .net 4 client profile, changing to .net 4 didn't change result. Also, the "Include foreign key columns" box is was. Thanks!